# Orientation detection for camera capture

Tags: camera, orientation, titanium, appcelerator

I've been searching for a solution to this for some time and believe that it, at it's core, isn't possible.

I'm wondering if anybody has found a decent hack or bypass.

My issue is this:

I have an app that captures a photo, then that photo is used as a canvas that the user can tap on to place tags.

After the tags are placed the user uploads the photos and the tags get submitted to a client service for parsing.

**If the photo is taken in landscape I need to detect if it's landscape left or landscape right so that I can display it at the proper orientation when it gets to the canvas, and flip it the proper direction if the user changes to the opposite landscape mode.**

How could I capture the orientation that the photo was taken in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getOrientation(o) {
    switch (o){
        case Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT:
            return 'portrait';
        case Titanium.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT:
            return 'upside portrait';
        case Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT:
            return 'landscape left';
        case Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT:
            return 'landscape right';
        case Titanium.UI.FACE_UP:
            return 'face up';
        case Titanium.UI.FACE_DOWN:
            return 'face down';
        case Titanium.UI.UNKNOWN:
            return 'unknown';
        }
    }
}

Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange',function(e){
    Ti.API.info('Current Orientation: ' + getOrientation(Titanium.Gesture.orientation));
    var orientation = getOrientation(e.orientation);
    Titanium.API.info(
        "orientation changed = "+orientation+", is     portrait?"+e.source.isPortrait()+", orientation = "+Ti.Gesture.orientation + "is landscape?"+e.source.isLandscape()
    );
});
```

modified a bit from the [KS](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/orientation.js) but should do the trick.

this should do what the above doesn't

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    success:function(event) {
    var orientationWhilePictureTaken = Ti.Gesture.orientation;
        // all other camera code...
    }
});
```

Comment: That works if you rotate the device, my issue is I need the orientation from when the image was captured. The above would change every time the device orientation changes.

Comment: No, photos taken with the app. I had written a function similar to what you presented but if the user changes orientation then the return changes.

Comment: If you are taking the picture in your app then you can capture the orientation with `Ti.Gesture.orientation` and save it somewhere then for each photo take within your app you would know the orientation.

Comment: must have over complicated it, I've tried Ti.Gesture.orientation but it never seemed to work, but once I put in yours, @Brian, worked like a charm. thank you sir!

Comment: @joseym how did you rotate the image back to normal position?? Can you please share it?

Answer (score 2):

Simply look at the height and width of `event.media` to at least determine portrait vs. landscape.  This will not help you with which direction to flip, though I'm not sure why you need to figure that out from the capture.  The image is saved as a landscape photo in the correct natural orientation, such that you would simply rotate it to the current orientation of the phone

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    success: function(event) { 
        var isLandscape = event.media.width > event.media.height;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, i'm already testing to see if width is greater than height. That, however, doesn't allow me to rotate to the proper position on screen change.